# A new project using Spring Initializr does not run in browser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-initializr

Building a new project downloaded using https://start.spring.io/ does not run on browser.
I have seen some solutions on stackoverflow which require to make some changes or add, but default/out-of-the-box application does not run.

I asked this in Github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20603 but was told that i need to add request mappings or something else. There's no default mapping for the root. That's indeed the default error page showing you a 404.

Is there a documentation to "add request mappings or something else" ? It will help if the application run showing some text instead of an error message. This maybe a simple obvious thing for Spring developers but for learners, takes a lot of effort.

http://localhost:8080/

[image]

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

Download new project at https://start.spring.io/

[image]

`mvn clean package`

[image]

`mvn spring-boot:run`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior right after creating a fresh Spring Boot project. The initializer does not register any endpoint for you, it just gives you the project skeleton you can start working with.

If you want to *see* something on `localhost:8080/` consider adding the following Java class to your project:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

  @GetMapping
  public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }

}
```

If you are new to Spring/Spring Boot, I can recommend the following resources:

- [Official Spring Web documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web)
- [Spring Boot Guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)
- Developing a CRUD API with Spring Boot [YouTube course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzZV25YsSpk&list=PLFjB4VDnlT_1UiOhFPAU3iBM7eQBnSD0k)